# How to delete a single git repository clone, without the rm -rf sledgehammer?

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

It is not possible to remove a git repo simply with `rm -r`, because the `.git` directory contains lots of write-protected files. I have *permission* to delete these as I'm the owner, but it's not feasible to confirm them all one by one.

Now, it is possible to do it all in one command by adding the `-f` flag to `rm`, but that means I lose all protection against deleting stuff that's protected for good reason. Like, for instance, another git repository with local branches that I haven't pushed yet.

But it seems the only way, so I've found myself doing `rm -rf` quite a lot lately, but I always feel uneasy about it. Is there a better way to get rid of a single repo clone, that will not ask about thousands of individual files but *will* fail if I try to erase something but a single repo? Ideally, it should also check that the repo I'm trying to delete has some up-to-date remote, before actually deleting it.

---

I don't quite see what's unclear about this question... it is this:

*How do I delete a repository with all contents, using commands that would **not** also nuke any other directory with write-protected files in it?*

Comment: Not sure if such a thing exists already, but presumably a shell script would suffice here?

Comment: That is quite a lot of logic that you're asking for: "delete a directory IF a command returns a particular exit code BUT NOT  some subdirectories identified by a particular file (`.git`)".  That sounds like something you would need to code up yourself.  I'll admit; I don't see the problem you're trying to solve: in what situations are you deleting repositories and you're not sure if they contain other repositories that maybe you don't want to delete?

Comment: @larsks I don't delete repositories that I'm not sure contain other repositories, but I delete repositories that sit in the same directory (or at least, _in the same unix tree_) as other stuff I want to keep. So whilst I don't mistype any paths ever, there is indeed no problem, but I prefer not making it easier than necessary to shoot myself in the foot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you collect all garbage objects:

```
git gc --prune=all
```

Then only one pack file remains, which is read-only, and the corresponding pack index, which is also read-only. Now

```
cd ..
rm -r repo
```

will ask only twice for confirmation instead of thousands of times.

This does not protect against removal of checked-out submodules, though.

Answer (score 4):

You may create a little bash function in your .bashrc:

```
function rmgit() {
    # Recursively apply write permissions to files in the .git folder
    chmod -R +w "${1}/.git"
    # Remove the clone
    rm -r "${1}"
}
```

Start a new shell and you should now being able to:

```
rmgit /path/to/clone
```

Comment: Works. This is what I'll go with as it does the job and is substantially faster than `git gc --prune=all`. I still accepted the other answer, because it feels a more “correct” and safe solution.